Fail to install R package "terra" in Conda environment
I'm setting up a MacOS laptop with a Conda environment (here named "r_env") and am encountering error messages when trying to install the R package "terra". Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Following error is produced:

> install.packages('terra')
Installing package into ‘/Users/ft/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/cran/src/contrib/terra_1.7-71.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 836573 bytes (816 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 816 KB

* installing *source* package ‘terra’ ...
** package ‘terra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
configure: CC: arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang
configure: CXX: arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang++ -std=gnu++17
checking for gdal-config... /opt/anaconda3/envs/r_env/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 3.8.4
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.1... yes
checking for arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-gcc... arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang accepts -g... yes
checking for arm64-apple-darwin20.0.0-clang option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for gdal.h... yes
checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... yes
checking GDAL: /opt/anaconda3/envs/r_env/share/gdal/pcs.csv readable... no
checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available for linking:... yes
checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available for running:... dyld[4535]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libgdal.34.dylib
  Referenced from: <77AD9583-9BF2-33BE-B6AF-B9DE29216B97> /private/var/folders/mg/dbb5s6cn0515h5msqv6clwpr0000gp/T/RtmpPr9ZBY/R.INSTALL107934ca07d1/terra/gdal_proj
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libgdal.34.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libgdal.34.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
./configure: line 3682:  4535 Abort trap: 6           ./gdal_proj
no
configure: error: OGRCoordinateTransformation() does not return a coord.trans: PROJ not available?
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’


R is installed inside the enviroment and has the following sessionInfo():
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20.0.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.6.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /opt/anaconda3/envs/r_env/lib/libblas.3.9.0.dylib 
LAPACK: /opt/anaconda3/envs/r_env/lib/liblapack.3.9.0.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.3 tools_4.3.3   

The Conda environment should possess all relevant packages:
conda list | grep gdal
gdal                      3.8.4           py312h56161e1_0    conda-forge
libgdal                   3.8.4                ha86f356_0    conda-forge

conda list | grep proj
proj                      9.3.1                h93d94ba_0    conda-forge
r-rprojroot               2.0.4             r43hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge


I've tried linking the libraries that I've located in the environment's directory, receiving the same error message as above.
install.packages('terra',configure.args="--with-gdal-lib=/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_env/lib/ --with-proj-lib=/opt/anaconda3/envs/r_env/lib/")


I've also tried installing 'terra' with shared libraries to possibly widen the search for the libraries of interest. The installation moves much further along and an error message is produced near the end:
...
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘terra’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/ft/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/00LOCK-terra/00new/terra/libs/terra.dylib':
  dlopen(/Users/ft/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/00LOCK-terra/00new/terra/libs/terra.dylib, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '__Z6Rlog1pd'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/ft/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/terra’

And I've explored installing "r-terra" into the conda environment, but fail to find the package in the main channels:

conda install terra
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - terra

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
  - defaults


